# Can you save an image with a grid in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, save

i am working with an image in Photoshop and applied grid but now I want to save that image with the grid.  Is there any procedure to save images with a grid?

Comment: Define "applied a grid".

Comment: To clarify @Scott's question: There's multiple ways to apply a grid in Photoshop, most of them not involving the grid you see when you choose View > Show > Grid.

Comment: @Bakabaka Actually.. to clarify, there is **only 1 way** to ***apply*** a grid I'm aware of, via the Vanishing Point filter. However, if you apply that grid it becomes pixels and thus part of the image, making the question completely intelligible since the pixels *are* indeed "saved with the image". There are many ways to ***use*** a grid in Photoshop, but whether or not that's the question is also unclear.

Comment: @Bakabaka thanks,i think u understand my question.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this also the alternative way :-

You could make a pattern that is the size of one grid square (make a square selection, stroke the selection, then go to the edit menu and "define pattern" and then fill a layer with the pattern you made (edit menu, fill, use pattern, then custom pattern, choose the pattern you just made) and save the image....

Comment: I don't understand how **anyone** else is supposed to provide answers when your questions are really only clear to yourself. "How to create a pattern" makes perfect sense.... "How to apply a grid" makes **no sense**.

Answer (score -2):

Take a print screen by using print screen key of your keyboard.